# Would 99,9% Isopropyl alcohol damage plastic of Bratz doll boxes?

Tags: plastics

I am a Bratz doll collector for quite some time now. I collect them boxed, most of the boxes and packagings are mint enough for me but I also have a few older ones which are quite dirty.

I’ve read some things online that cleaning with Isopropyl alcohol will take off most of the dirt and at the same time it will desinfect it as well. It seems perfect!
But since I invested a lot of money in my collection over the years, I would like to know for sure if Isopropyl alcohol 99,9% could harm my plastic Bratz doll boxes in any way?

I enclosed a picture of a Bratz doll box, if needed.

Thanks in advance for answering my question! =) [image]

Comment: I suspect you are going to have to try it. Without knowing eactly what the packaging is made of it, is difficult to answer.

Comment: Though it *probably* wont harm it, cleaning collectibles or antiques usually *reduces* resale value. Only do this is it's just a keepsake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the materials your collectibles are made of. Use a 33% v/v solution for a relatively harmless wash. Two parts of water to one part of Isopropyl alcohol that you have